# What does the box say?

Tags: translation

I need this translated urgently. I'm sorry if you're tired of such questions, but I tried to draw the kanjis in two sites, to find them by radicals, to use a OCR program, but nothing helped.

[image: halp]

Comment: `贺 保加利亚欧洲工业大学成立五周年` and `中国 中南民族大学 赠`, means `Congratulations on the fifth anniversary of Bulgaria European Industrial University` and `From China South-Central University For Nationalities`. BTW: The picture is upside down.

Comment: In my opinion, we should follow a moderate standard for the posts that ask for translation. Of course, I agree posts asking for bulk translation should be deemed as *off-topic*, but the rule **"unless prior research effort is clearly indicated" itself looks unclear to me** -- anyone who come here to ask for such kinds of translation probably fail in many ways they've tried, and generally, a native speaker who would like to answer the question isn't interested in how they failed.

Comment: @Stan I don't think 'prior research effort' is the heart of the principle but merely the enforcement and manifestation for translation questions. Having gone through the entire help center, my take is the heart of the principle is 'serious learner' as opposed to 'passing interest'. If I am correct, translation questions should be off-topic even with 'prior research effort' if that is only for a one-time practical purpose.

Comment: Can you rotate the picture before posting it...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photo is upside down, rotate it by 180 degrees to view it correctly.
The writing goes from top right to bottom left.

I can only type Simplified characters, but they are the same.

The first column (right hand side): 贺 保加利亚欧洲工业大学成立五周年
The second column (left hand side): 中国 中南民族大学 赠

The translation is roughly this: Congratulations on the 5th anniversary of the founding of the European Polytechnical University, Bulgaria; Bestowed by South-Central University for Nationalities, China

This is how you should read it, the first 'line' is marked with blue, the second with red.

Here is the Wikipedia page on [the South-Central University for Nationalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Central_University_for_Nationalities). It is different from another Chinese university known as the [Central South University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_South_University).

[image]