# Rockwell's Chinese Newspaper

Tags: translation, culture

> Note: I've seen [prior translation questions](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/13984/what-does-the-box-say) closed, but I think this is different--as it is a matter of public interest and possible disinformation--as opposed to "found a piece of paper in the attic, tell me what it says".

Rockwell is a fairly paranoid fellow, made famous by his ["Somebody's Watching Me"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YvAYIJSSZY) song.  *(The FBI ultimately [declassified the surveillance program](http://www.theonion.com/article/fbi-discontinues-surveillance-of-rockwell-501).)*

The top hit I can find for what the paper says claims the headline of the following paper is ["ROCKWELL FOR GOD’S SAKE LOCK YOUR DOOR FOR ONCE."](http://grantland.com/hollywood-prospectus/rembert-explains-the-80s-rockwells-somebodys-watching-me/)

[image: Rockwell's Chinese Newspaper]

Call me a skeptic.  But I doubt that.  (I generally doubt the paper was printed for the video.)

Despite precedent of not allowing translation questions, I beseech you to give a reputable top-Internet-ranked answer to this question others must wonder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The news paper was '國際日報 (International Daily)'

The headline had nothing to do with the quote. It said "US dollar rise to new record high"

Subheading 1: "Eight nations' central bank intervene "

Subheading 2: "Gold price everywhere uniformly..." ( text below not shown, but I guess it was 'raise')

Comment: Thank you!  Google Translates corroborates the title, in that it says ["World Daily"](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%E4%B8%96%E7%95%8C%E6%97%A5%E5%A0%B1), which within the bounds of translation seems pretty fair.  :-)  I guess the question of whether the financial nature of the headlines has meaning or not by those making the video is up to the viewer.  As a bit of a systems thinker, I always wonder if "nonsense" is actually "nonsense" or a hack...!

Comment: Sorry, 世界日報 is the paper we have here in Toronto. The correct name for the newspaper in the picture is '國際日報 (International Daily)' -answer edited.

Comment: Interesting to know exactly which paper it is, if it's [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Daily_News) then maybe that link could be in the answer...